# Is it possible to make circle (curved) blocks in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Please dont tell to place square blocks in some specific manner - so as it might look close to circle from far... I had used little tiles mod (in which blocks can be breaked into smaller pieces and reused), but I didn't get perfect curved surfaces. 
I need to have perfect circle (curved) blocks for my design.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Extra Utilities mod adds items called Impossible Objects, which are spheres

**Christmas tree decorated with Impossible Objects**
[image: Christmas tree decorated with Impossible Objects]

Answer (score 3):

There's also Architecture Craft, which adds circles (and arches) to the game. It may be helpful.
[image: Image of a series of arch blocks arranged to make a circle]

Here is the link.
http://www.9minecraft.net/architecturecraft-mod/

Answer (score 0):

If you want bloody perfect circles larger then 1 block, use invisible minecarts with blocks on them, arranged in a circle. It's hard to explain, and uses tons of command blocks, so I'd recommend [watching this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Mre06nqUs0)

But this would take up lots of time and space, so instead, you can do it the non-command-block way:

Dig a hole 1 block wide and 2 deep. Then take a mob spawn egg (I recommend chicken) and right-clock into the hole. After a minute or two, stop, and look inside. You got yourself a perfect circle in the middle of the hole.